# C code for http-webdav client using the CURLlibrary

Tags: network-programming, libcurl, webdav

I am searching for c code for http-webdav client using the CURL library with authentication enabled.

I have tried with some of the sample codes provided by the CURL , but nothing seem to pass the authentication methods and work.

I have enabled the digest authentication with the user and password.
The client request is sent correctly but the server response is 301.
I have captured the packets using the wireshark.
Is there any thing that is missing?

Below is the code I have tried.

```
/* read callback function, fread() look alike */
static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  ssize_t retcode;
  curl_off_t nread;

  int *fdp = (int *)stream;
  int fd = *fdp;

  retcode = read(fd, ptr, size * nmemb);

  nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

  fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
          " bytes from file\n", nread);

  return retcode;
}


/*
 * This example shows a HTTP PUT operation. PUTs a file given as a command
 * line argument to the URL also given on the command line.
 *
 * This example also uses its own read callback.
 *
 * Here's an article on how to setup a PUT handler for Apache:
 * http://www.apacheweek.com/features/put
 */ 


int curlApache ()
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  FILE * hd_src;
  struct stat file_info;

  char *file;
  char *url;

  char error;

  file = "/bd0/filecreate.txt";
  url = "http://10.1.20.127/sites/";
  //url = "http://10.1.21.14/webdav/test.txt";

  struct curl_slist *slist = NULL; 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Accept: text/xml"); 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Depth: infinity"); 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Connection: Keep-Alive"); 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: text/xml"); 
  slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Expect:"); 

  /* get the file size of the local file */ 
  stat(file, &file_info);

  hd_src = fopen(file, "a+");
  if (hd_src == NULL)             
  printf("Disc full or no permission\n");



  const char *str = "This is the file content";
  const char read[24];
      if (hd_src != NULL) 
      if (fputs (str, hd_src) != EOF); 
      if( fgets (read, 24, hd_src)!=NULL ) {
            /* writing content to stdout */
            puts(read);
         }

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* get a curl handle */ 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 3L);

    /* we want to use our own read function */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

    /* enable uploading */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* HTTP PUT please */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1L);

    /* tell libcurl we can use "any" auth, which lets the lib pick one, but it
            also costs one extra round-trip and possibly sending of all the PUT
            data twice!!! */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, (long)CURLAUTH_DIGEST); 


   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:nimo0630");

    fseek(hd_src, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int file_size;
    file_size = ftell(hd_src);

    Curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, hd_src);
    Curl_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, file_size);

    /* specify target URL, and note that this URL should include a file
       name, not only a directory */  

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    /* now specify which file to upload */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

    /* provide the size of the upload, we specicially typecast the value
       to curl_off_t since we must be sure to use the correct data size */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);

    /* Now run off and do what you've been told! */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));


        if(!res) {
          /* extract the available authentication types */
        long auth;
        res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_HTTPAUTH_AVAIL, &auth);
        if(!res) 
        {
            if(!auth)
            printf("No auth available, perhaps no 401?\n");
            else
            {     
                printf("%s%s%s%s\n", \
                    auth & CURLAUTH_BASIC ? "Basic ":"", \
                    auth & CURLAUTH_DIGEST ? "Digest ":"", \
                    auth & CURLAUTH_NEGOTIATE ? "Negotiate ":"", \
                    auth % CURLAUTH_NTLM ? "NTLM ":"");
            }

        }
        }
    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  fclose(hd_src); /* close the local file */ 

  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the code of your attempts, describe what doesn't work and someone might be able to help. We do not write your home work for you!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my code with description. The problem is with the server response. I have tried PUT to the IIS and Apache webdav server with CURL commands and it works fine. When I try with the code I have 301 response from the server. I understand there is some thing missing in the code.

Comment: If you get 301, the authentication worked. Enable `CURL_VERBOSE` and you might even see that. You probably want to enable redirect-following with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`...